# Limit of $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\sqrt{x^8+4}-x^4)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, radicals

I have to determine the following:

$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\sqrt{x^8+4}-x^4)$

$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\sqrt{x^8+4}-x^4)=\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}(\sqrt{x^8(1+\frac{4}{x^8})}-x^4 = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}(x^4\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x^8}}-x^4 = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}(x^4(\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x^8}}-1)= \infty$

Could somebody please check, if my solution is correct?

Comment: This is a good start except for the final conclusion.  When you take the limit of a product and one term goes to zero and the other to infinity, you usually need to convert it to a quotient so you can use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\sqrt{x^8+4}-x^4)=(\sqrt{x^8+4}-x^4)\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1)=\sqrt{x^8+4}-x^4$$Now seriously, the last equality is wrong, you have $+\infty\times 0$.

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is unknown for us so far

Answer (score 10):

This is indeterminate because $x^4\rightarrow \infty$, but $\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x^8}}-1\rightarrow 0$.  You can multiply by the conjugate
$$
\left(\sqrt{x^8+4}-x^4\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^8+4}+x^4}{\sqrt{x^8+4}+x^4}\right)=\frac{x^8+4-x^8}{\sqrt{x^8+4}+x^4}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{x^8+4}+x^4}
$$

Answer (score 4):

A short way to (non-rigorously) find the limit is to observe that for large $x$, 
$$
\sqrt{x^8+4} \approx \sqrt{x^8}=x^4
$$
so that for large $x$ (especially in $\lim_{x \to \infty}$)
$$
\sqrt{x^8+4}-x^4 \approx x^4-x^4=0
$$
So the limit must be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$
x^4 (\sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{x^8}}-1)=
x^4 (\frac{2}{x^8} + O(x^{-8}))
=\frac{2}{x^4} + O (x^{-4}) \rightarrow 0
$$
when $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Landau "big-O" notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)? It might be useful in making this answer a bit more rigorous.

Comment: @Ti-Kong ng : yes, your answer doesn't look like it makes sense the way you wrote it (I did not downvote).

Comment: Sorry, i rewrite it in a way more rigorous.